# Jasmine Karme Unit test - AngularJs Directive is not getting compiled

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, directive

**I am having issues testing angularjs directive. Following is my test:**

```
it('should be defined', inject(function($compile,$rootScope){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = $compile('<div><some-directive-name></some-directive-name></div>')($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        console.log(element[0].outerHTML);
        expect(element.html()).toBe(template);
    }));
```

Output for the console.log comes as

```
'<div class="ng-scope"><some-directive-name></some-directive-name></div>'
```

Instead it should be the template URL of **someDirectiveName** directive

Directive:

```
angular.module('app.moduleName').directive('someDirectiveName', function (someService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/path/partials/some-directive-name.tpl.html',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element) {
   ......
   ......
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: @Greg Thank you for responding. Actually I was not getting any exception.
But I found the issue. I didn't added reference of the js directive file to karma config.
Its a stupid mistake. 
Thanks though

Comment: @Greg I have another similar question if you can please help with:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604276/angularjs-unit-test-directive-how-can-i-pass-a-function-to-a-directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not getting any exception. But I found the issue. I didn't added reference of the js directive file to karma config. Its a stupid mistake